# Group Top n values by date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have the following dataset in pandas:

```
Item ID     Order Date
1           2019-09-01
2           2019-09-01
3           2019-09-01
...
2           2019-10-11
3           2019-10-11
3           2019-10-12
```

I would like to retrieve the top10 ordered items from the whole dataset and group them by the order date. It might happen that on some days these items have not been ordered.

I can get the top 10 of the whole dataset by `dataset['Item ID'].value_counts().head(10)`.

`dataset.groupby(['Order Date','Item ID']).count()` gets me all items for the given day, but not the total top10 of the whole dataset and the amount they have been ordered on the given day.

I have tried to filter the dataset with the top10 items first. In a second step I would then group by the submit date, but I am not sure, whether this is a smart solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is first filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) by index values of `top`, then create ordered [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html), so last sorting working like you need:

```
top = dataset['Item ID'].value_counts().head(10)

dataset = dataset[dataset['Item ID'].isin(top.index)]

dataset['Item ID'] = pd.Categorical(dataset['Item ID'], ordered=True, categories=top.index)

dataset = dataset.sort_values(['Order Date','Item ID'])
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me. I am though struggling to plot the `0` values. In a first step, I have done `dataset.fillna(0)`, but the time series plot is not plotting the values, meaning there is no drop to 0, it is just blank, where there should be a 0.